# How can I determine when a commit in the Flutter engine repo is available on a given Flutter SDK channel?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to be able to find out how I can tell when a specific merge commit on the Flutter engine repo (eg. this PR's: https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/10434  had an "engine roll" merge of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/37531) is available of a specific Flutter SDK channel, ie. when its in the engine used on current version of the Flutter SDK in the dev, beta, stable channels.

Comment: Maybe it might help:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Where%27s-my-Commit%3F

Comment: @dudeck thank you that's exactly what I was looking for! If you put it in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.